# Keeping last 24 hours of log in pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I need to keep a log of records (sensor data) in pandas.Dataframe, but I only need to keep last 24 hours of them. A new record arrives every second.

Records have format of:

`{'Date': ..., 'Sensor1': 10, 'Sensor2': 12, ...}`

Where 'Date' should also be the index of the DataFrame.

Of course, it's possible to use:

`df = df.append( newRecord )
df.drop( df[df.Date < datetime.now() - timedelta( hours=24 )].index] )`

But I feel it's ugly.

What is the most efficient and panda-ish way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use `subset` with [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for removing rows, but is is not the fastest method. You can set column `Date` to `index` and then chop `DataFrame` by time `end`.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime

#create testing DataFrame
def format_time():
    t = datetime.datetime.now()
    s = t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return pd.to_datetime(s)

start = format_time()
print start
2016-03-13 09:12:44

N = 85000
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.Series(pd.date_range(start - pd.Timedelta(days=1, minutes=20) , periods=N, freq='s')), 'a': range(N)})
print df.head()
                 Date  a
0 2016-03-12 08:52:44  0
1 2016-03-12 08:52:45  1
2 2016-03-12 08:52:46  2
3 2016-03-12 08:52:47  3
4 2016-03-12 08:52:48  4
```

```
#set index from column Date  
df = df.set_index('Date')
#print df

#find chopping time
end = start - pd.Timedelta(days=1)
print end
2016-03-12 09:12:44

#boolean indexing
df1 = df[(df.index >= end ) & (df.index <= start)]
#chopping method
df2 = df[end:]

#test equality
print df1.equals(df2)
True
```

Testing:

```
In [87]: %timeit df[(df.index >= end ) & (df.index <= start)]
The slowest run took 4.01 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.75 ms per loop

In [88]: %timeit df[end:]
The slowest run took 6.84 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 120 µs per loop
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem of chopping data frame efficiently. It is about 85K records, and copying it every second (during chopping) seems to be very inefficient. Furthermore, the data is very structured (it can only be chopped from the beginning) and I want to use the benefit (if it exist) it provides.

Is there a kind of 'lazy indexing' when boolean indexing stops the first time it does not hold?
Thanks!

Comment: *the first time the condition does not hold. I mean maybe it is possible to use a binary search to locate the first date to be cut.

Comment: Or is it possible to use some kind of hierarchical indexing to chop every, say, hour, and the rest of the time to use indexing?

Comment: Basically, what you call 'chopping' creates view (i.e. does not actually chop, so df will grow more and more), but I think I can continue from here. Didn't actually think Pandas is already that blazing fast. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 2):

dropping reorganize the all dataframe each second, it's a costly operation:

```
In [6]: %timeit  df.drop(4)
10 loops, best of 3: 17.3 ms per loop
```

It  can be avoid here with a fixed rolling buffer to store efficiently sensor data. The index is just an integer, one per second in a day.

```
aday=24*3600
date=pd.date_range('00:00:00', periods=aday, freq='S')
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':date,'Sensor1':rand(aday),'Sensor2':rand(aday)})
```

This way adding a sample is very fast :

```
sample={'Date': pd.Timestamp('2016-12-04 12:00:00'), 'Sensor1': .1, 'Sensor2': .2}


def indexer(t):
    return t.hour*3600+t.minute*60+t.second

def set(df,sample):
    date=sample['Date']
    index=indexer(date)
    df.iat[index,0]=sample['Date']
    df.iat[index,1]=sample['Sensor1']
    df.iat[index,2]=sample['Sensor2']


In [7]: %timeit set(df,sample)
1000 loops, best of 3: 141 µs per loop
```

to dump the current last 24 hours, just do :

```
dfnow=df.set_index(df['Date']).sort_index().copy()
```

time is now the index.

Comment: Thank you for the very nice approach (I learned something new here). There is a small problem with this approach (the fix isn't difficult apparently, but I'd think about the pandas-style solution). The problem is if for some reason sensor data was skipped for a particular second, the old data will be stored. I think, for the perfect solution something similar to ffill() should be used between the last index and the current one.